# Индексирование Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, index

Есть массив, из которого случайным образом выбираются индексы:

```
np.random.seed(42)
arr = np.arange(10)
random_indexes = np.random.choice(arr, size=arr.shape[0])
print(arr[random_indexes])
```

На выходе будет:

```
array([6, 3, 7, 4, 6, 9, 2, 6, 7, 4])
```

Необходимо вернуть значения массива, индексы которых не выбирались:

```
array([0, 1, 5, 8])
```

Есть ли иной способ вернуть их, кроме как:

```
arr[~np.in1d(arr, np.unique(arr[random_indexes]))]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно через list comprehension, а можно так:

```
rest = np.delete(arr, random_indexes)
```

> array([0, 1, 5, 8])

Answer (score 5):

Можно использовать [numpy.setdiff1d()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html), чтобы найти разницу множеств:

```
In [173]: np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(arr)), random_indexes)
Out[173]: array([0, 1, 5, 8])
```

если `arr` всегда будет создаваться при помощи `np.arange(N)`, тогда решение можно упростить:

```
In [174]: np.setdiff1d(arr, random_indexes)
Out[174]: array([0, 1, 5, 8])
```